# Unreal - Where should I put my 'Save System Controller'

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, savegame

Making a save game system for a single player platformer game in Unreal.

- Needs to be accessible from the Main Menu
- Cannot be a component on the player.

Where is the best place to put/store this functionality?

- GameMode?
- GameState?
- PlayerState even?

Comment: Which of these have you tried? Are you unsatisfied with the results of what you've tried so far?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm asking this more as an 'accepted approach' question - where I want to know how I'm 'supposed' to do this, to fit in with Unreal

Comment: There is no authority who "Accepts" or "Refuses to Accept" your approach. If your approach works and meets your goals, that is the only thing that matters. If your approach is *not* working or *not* meeting your goals in some way, ask here about that specific shortfall and we can help you solve it.

Comment: It doesnt matter - you can even store it in singleton.